# PHP Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 32 in

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В последнее время стала возникать куча вот таких ошибок:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 32 in. /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/tovary/index.php on line 175
```

Цифра 32 динамична (т.е. постоянно меняется там, бывает 28, бывает 18, 20 и т.д.)
Вот что находится на линии 175:

```
preg_match('/'.$last.'\|(.*)/', $all, $match);
```

Как исправить ошибку?

**UPD**: путем перебора вычислил, что ошибка возникает при попадании в переменную $last следующих символов: {[}].

Поэтому прошу дать регулярное выражение по удалению этих символов из переменной $last.

P.S. Прошу только потому, что в регулярках не могу разобраться.

Comment: Я бы первым делом попробовал `\` после `$last` на `/` заменить)

Comment: timka_s, last постоянно выводится как ".".

Comment: Передал данные серверу: $^&456ds45. Получил в ответ: <code>/$^&456ds45\|(.*)/</code>\

Comment: Kremchik, если так сделать, то все перестает работать.

Comment: А что вы храните в переменной `$last`?

Comment: Как я понял из скрипта, там хранятся слова, которые потом заменяются на слова из определенного файла.

P.S. Скрипт покупной. Автор не помогает...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$last` нужно экранировать. Функция [`preg_quote()`](http://ua.php.net/preg_quote)

```
preg_match('/' . preg_quote($last) . '\|(.*)/', $all, $match);
```